# Какой класс отвечает за первоначальное формирование массива arResult в комплексном компоненте новости?

Tags: битрикс

Какой класс отвечает за первоначальное формирование массива `$arResult` в комплексном компоненте новости?

Answer (score 0):

Документация по структуре комплексного компонента: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2749

Сам компонент можно посмотреть в `/bitrix/components/bitrix/news/`